# How do I input color values into the Adobe color picker in hexadecimal?

Tags: colors, adobe-illustrator, hexadecimal

I have some C# code (though it could be any language) and I am trying to copy the colors used therein into an Illustrator design.

Here's the code:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, SolidColorBrush> _DefaultModeColours = new Dictionary<string, SolidColorBrush>
{
    { "null", new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00)) },
    { "lean-back", new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0x69, 0xB4)) },
    { "respite", new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xDB, 0x00, 0x00)) },
    { "purposeful", new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00)) },
    { "opportunistic", new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x0C, 0x06, 0x40)) },
    { "orienting", new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x92, 0xBC, 0xE5)) }
};
```

The colors are specified using hexadecimal numbers for the ARGB values. In Illustrator I have the following color chooser:

[image: Adobe color picker and error message]

I could fire up a calculator and convert each of the (nonobvious) hex values into decimal, but I imagine there is an easy way to change the Illustrator settings for the document to use hex values. Is there? If so where do I set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You double click the fill or the stroke from the left side menu. Then you can input the hex.

[image]

Then you will see a popup exactly like Photoshop

[image]

You can then type in the Hex number (by the # symbol).

[Source](http://www.namepros.com/graphic-design-flash/234348-adobe-illustrator-hex-code.html)

Comment: Great answer - thanks Dave. It hadn't occurred to me that they were double-clickable. Doh.

Comment: You will be surprised (at least I was) about how many things are double clickable and how many shortcuts exist. And I mean shortcuts on the keyboard where no option exists in the Context menu (or may be I just never found them)! Totally off topic but I think you could learn illustrator for life to only be shown something new the follow day!

Comment: Just also note, if you're using C# then WPF allows you to set the transparency. I don't know how this would affect the colour/hex code.